# How to remove some elements from a set?

Tags: dolphindb

For instance, I have a set like this:

```py
y=set(8 2 4 6)
```

How to remove the element 6?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [erase!](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/FunctionsandCommands/FunctionReferences/e/erase!.html) function.

Example:

```py
y=set(8 2 4 6) 
y.erase!(6)
```

Result:

[image]